# Writing to a file or stdout in Rust

Tags: file, stdio, rust

I'm learning Rust, and I'm somewhat stumped.

I'm trying to give the user the option of writing output to stdout or to a supplied filename.

I started with the example code that's given for using `extra::getopts` located [here](http://static.rust-lang.org/doc/0.9/extra/getopts/index.html). From there, in the `do_work` function, I'm trying to do this:

```rust
use std::io::stdio::stdout;
use std::io::buffered::BufferedWriter;

fn do_work( input: &str, out: Option<~str> ) {
    println!( "Input:  {}", input );
    println!( "Output: {}", match out {
        Some(x) => x,
        None    => ~"Using stdout"
    } );
    let out_writer = BufferedWriter::new( match out {
        // I know that unwrap is frowned upon, 
        // but for now I don't want to deal with the Option.
        Some(x) => File::create( &Path::new( x ) ).unwrap(),
        None    => stdout()
    } );
    out_writer.write( bytes!( "Test output\n" ) );
}
```

But it outputs the following error:

```
test.rs:25:43: 28:6 error: match arms have incompatible types: expected `std::io::fs::File` but found `std::io::stdio::StdWriter` (expected struct std::io::fs::File but found struct std::io::stdio::StdWriter)
test.rs:25     let out_writer = BufferedWriter::new( match out {
test.rs:26         Some(x) => File::create( &Path::new( x ) ).unwrap(),
test.rs:27         None    => stdout()
test.rs:28     } );
test.rs:25:22: 25:41 error: failed to find an implementation of trait std::io::Writer for [type error]
test.rs:25     let out_writer = BufferedWriter::new( match out {
                            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

But I don't understand what the issue is because both `File` and `StdWriter` implement the `Writer` Trait. Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, both implement `Write`, but the problem is `BufWriter` is expecting a type `T` that implements `Writer`, and that `T` can't be `File` and `Stdout` at the same time.

You must cast both to the common type (either `Box<dyn Write>` or `&dyn Write`, but since you cannot return references you have to use `Box`):

```
fn do_work(input: &str, out: Option<String>) {
    let mut out_writer: Box<dyn Write> = BufWriter::new(match out {
        Some(ref x) => Box::new(File::create(&Path::new(x)).unwrap()),
        None => Box::new(stdout()),
    });
    out_writer.write(b"Test output\n").unwrap();
}
```

You should also handle errors properly, not just using `unwrap` (used in example for simplicity).

Comment: Ohhhhhhhh. That makes sense. I wasn't aware that you had to explicitly state it as the Trait that you wanted. Thanks a lot!

Comment: The point is casting to the common type, not that type is a trait that `T` needs (it could be something else that implements `io::Writer`)

Comment: Since this answer was written, the tilde '~' has been removed from Rust and some changes concerning DSTs have been introduced. An update would be appreciated.

Answer (score 24):

A lot has changed in Rust since 2014, so here is an answer that works for me using Rust 1.15.1:

```
let out_writer = match out {
    Some(x) => {
        let path = Path::new(x);
        Box::new(File::create(&path).unwrap()) as Box<dyn Write>
    }
    None => Box::new(io::stdout()) as Box<dyn Write>,
};
```

This is pretty much the same as [@Arjan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22357980/155423), except that `~` was replaced by `Box`, and some names have changed. I'm leaving out `BufferedWriter`, but if you want that, I believe it is now named [`BufWriter`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/struct.BufWriter.html).

Comment: `let out_writer: Box<Write> = ... Box::new(io::stdout()),` (without `as ...`) also works at least in 1.16. I don't know which is more idiomatic.